# TCP Connection Socket Leak When Calling Google .NET API

Tags: c#, tcp, google-bigquery, google-api-dotnet-client

Recently during my test, I found my program hangs after a quite long period of time (around 2 hours or so). What my program does is basically streaming real-time data onto Google BigQuery through Google .NET Client API. Here's my code (in a member function of my BigQueryHelper.cs) :

```
try
        {
             TableDataInsertAllResponse response = await BigQueryService.Tabledata.InsertAll(request, _account.ProjectId, table.DataSetId, tableId).ExecuteAsync(ct); 

            IList<TableDataInsertAllResponse.InsertErrorsData> insertErrors = response.InsertErrors;
            if (insertErrors != null && insertErrors.Count > 0)
            {
                string message = string.Format("Failed to insert {0} out of {1} rows from {2} into {3}",
                    insertErrors.Count, rowList.Count, rowList[0]["FileName"],table);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(message);
                for (var i = 0; i < insertErrors.Count; i++)
                {
                    sb.Append(string.Format("{0}Error #{1}: {2},{3},{4}", Environment.NewLine, i + 1,
                        insertErrors[i].Errors[0].Location,insertErrors[i].Errors[0].Message, insertErrors[i].Errors[0].Reason));
                }
                TableDataInsertAllResponse.InsertErrorsData firstError = insertErrors[0];
                if (firstError != null)
                {
                    string firstMessage = firstError.Errors[0].Message;
                    string firstReason = firstError.Errors[0].Reason;
                    if (firstMessage != null && firstMessage.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("no such field"))
                    {
                        await UpdateTableSchemaAsync(table.DataSetId, table.TableId, table.Schema);
                    }
                    else if (firstReason != null && firstReason.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("timeout"))
                    {
                        sb.Append(string.Format("{0}Insert timeout on Bigquery side", Environment.NewLine));
                    }
                }

                throw new BigQueryException(sb.ToString(), insertErrors);
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            GoogleApiException googleException = ex as GoogleApiException;
            if (googleException != null)
            {
                if ((int) googleException.HttpStatusCode == 404)
                {
                    if (googleException.Message.Contains(table.TableId))
                    {
                        needCreateTable = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new BigQueryException("other GoogleApiException", googleException);
                }
            }
            else if (ex is BigQueryException)
            {
                throw;
            }
            else throw new BigQueryException(string.Format("Failed to insert {0} rows from {1} into {2}", rowList.Count, rowList[0]["FileName"], table), ex);
        }
        if (needCreateTable)
        {
            await CreateTableAsync(table);
            throw new BigQueryTableNotFoundException(table + " not found");
        }
```

I monitored my program using Process Explorer, I found no deadlock but all TCP connections to Google became "CLOSE_WAIT" and finally exhausted the pre-set connection limit (100) thus block other connection attempts. Here's I got from netstat: (il-in-f95:https points to Google)

```
  TCP    my ip:49158    il-in-f95:https        CLOSE_WAIT      20756
  TCP    my ip:49165    il-in-f95:https        CLOSE_WAIT      20756
  TCP    my ip:49166    il-in-f95:https        CLOSE_WAIT      20756
  TCP    my ip:49169    il-in-f95:https        CLOSE_WAIT      20756
  TCP    my ip:49170    il-in-f95:https        CLOSE_WAIT      20756
  TCP    my ip:49171    il-in-f95:https        CLOSE_WAIT      20756
  TCP    my ip:49172    il-in-f95:https        CLOSE_WAIT      20756
  TCP    my ip:49173    il-in-f95:https        CLOSE_WAIT      20756
  TCP    my ip:49174    il-in-f95:https        CLOSE_WAIT      20756
  TCP    my ip:49175    il-in-f95:https        CLOSE_WAIT      20756
  TCP    my ip:49176    il-in-f95:https        CLOSE_WAIT      20756
  TCP    my ip:49178    il-in-f95:https        CLOSE_WAIT      20756
  TCP    my ip:49179    il-in-f95:https        CLOSE_WAIT      20756
  TCP    my ip:49181    il-in-f95:https        CLOSE_WAIT      20756
  TCP    my ip:49182    il-in-f95:https        CLOSE_WAIT      20756
  TCP    my ip:49183    il-in-f95:https        CLOSE_WAIT      20756
  TCP    my ip:49185    il-in-f95:https        CLOSE_WAIT      20756
  TCP    my ip:49188    il-in-f95:https        CLOSE_WAIT      20756
  TCP    my ip:49189    il-in-f95:https        CLOSE_WAIT      20756
  TCP    my ip:49193    il-in-f95:https        CLOSE_WAIT      20756
  TCP    my ip:49196    il-in-f95:https        CLOSE_WAIT      20756
  TCP    my ip:49197    il-in-f95:https        CLOSE_WAIT      20756
  TCP    my ip:49372    il-in-f95:https        CLOSE_WAIT      20756
  TCP    my ip:49375    il-in-f95:https        CLOSE_WAIT      20756
  TCP    my ip:49376    il-in-f95:https        CLOSE_WAIT      20756
  TCP    my ip:49385    il-in-f95:https        CLOSE_WAIT      20756
  TCP    my ip:49386    il-in-f95:https        CLOSE_WAIT      20756
  TCP    my ip:49417    il-in-f95:https        CLOSE_WAIT      20756
  TCP    my ip:49629    il-in-f95:https        CLOSE_WAIT      20756
  ...there are more
```

"CLOSE_WAIT" essentially means that his is a state where socket is waiting for the application to execute close(). But since I'm calling Google API,and the httpClient calls are encapsulated in the API, I cannot control the close of any httpClient. Neither could I find a way to dispose or close TableDataInsertAllResponse. I digged more into BigQuery API call, and found the implementation is actually in Google .NET Client API, the call path finally goes to this method:

```
       private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteUnparsedAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using (var request = CreateRequest())
        {
            return await service.HttpClient.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
```

1. Am I using the API correctly?
2. if the answer to 1 is yes:  I'm wondering, if, whenever any exception happens at the closing bracket of the using statement, the request wouldn't be properly disposed and thus the underlying TCP connection wouldn't be closed properly?
3. I initialized BigQueryService, which is disposable indeed, only once in the lifetime of my BigQueryHelper.cs in its constructor. This instance is used during the lifetime of my program. is this a potential break-point? Would I rather create bigqueryservice instance everytime when I need to send a request and dispose it after request's end? Since there's a authorization process involved, I'm worried that this can slow down the performance.

Comment: which version of the bigquery dll did you download?  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2/

Comment: possibly related to https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/590 or open a new issue.

Comment: @DaImTo Google .NET API:1.9.3  BigQuery API: 1.9.2.2270

Comment: Try and import the previous big query nuget package.   We are having a problem with some of the packages for the latest build.  Let me know if it works please

Comment: @DaImTo I tried what I mentioned in the 3rd question above. the program ran all good for a whole night and I'll keep an eye on it today. But obviously, create and dispose BigqueryService object at every request helps to improve the situation. I wasn't be able to figure out what's behind the scene but my gut tells me that it's couldn't be the most efficient way, since at least it'll go through oauth every time right?

Comment: I think you should log this as an issue on the client library.    I will have a look.   It may be completely unrelated to the other issue.

Comment: Previous one is stable I am tracking some issues with the current on. If your dlls are signed it's the newest.

Comment: OK, I'll create a new issue in github.

Comment: @DalmTo the latest one is 1.9.2.2280, but do you mean 1.9.2.2240 is the stable one?

Comment: Install-Package Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2 -Version 1.9.2.2270 is stable  I would just like to ensure that this issue isn't related to our other issue it probably isnt.

Comment: @DalmTo, it's the one I'm having now and the one exposes this issue

Comment: ok i will check change logs see what was changed in that version.   .net framework 4.5?